# Four points lie on a line, the distance between them in increasing order is: 2, 3, k, 11, 12, 14. What is the value of k?

Tags: combinatorics

Four points lie on a line, the distance between them in increasing order is:

2, 3, k, 11, 12, 14. What is the value of k?

1. First of all, I think the word is ambiguous. Are we to assume that the distance is between each consecutive point (in which case there are too many distances) or are we to assume that the distance is between the first point and all the others, the second point and all the others, the third point and etc.?
2. I have seen that answer is supposed to be k=9. However, there is really not a logical explanation given the ambiguity of the question. It is not even a proper recurrence.

Comment: The distances are between all ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ possible pairs. Taking the points to lie on a number line, and since the largest distance is $14$, we may assume without loss of generality that one point is at $0$, another is at $14$, and the other two are somewhere in between.

Comment: Consider 4 number $a,b,c,d$ with $a<b<c<d$. We can calculate '''primary-distances''' : $b-a, c-b, d-c$, '''secondary-distances''' : $c-a, d-b$ and amplitude $d-a$ ; obviously $d-a=14$ ; sum of primary distances is amplitude, and primary distance are probably 2,3 and k ; it results k=9,and we can check that secondary-distances match with this result.

Answer (score 1):

For four numbers there are ${4\choose 2}=6$ possible gaps (distances) between pairs of numbers. We are given the gaps, in sorted order, between the four numbers:
$$2,3,k,11,12,14.\tag{$\ast$}
$$
First of all, the largest gap, $14$, must be the gap between the largest and smallest number.

Now look at the two numbers that have a gap of $2$ between them. These numbers cannot have a number between them, else there would two gaps in list $(\ast)$ that add up to $2$. Similarly the numbers that are separated by $3$ cannot have a number between them, else there would be two gaps in $(\ast)$ adding up to $3$. Therefore if we place the numbers from smallest to largest, the (three) gaps between adjacent numbers must be some permutation of $2$, $3$, and $9$, since these gaps must add up to $14$. This implies $k=9$.

To prove there is consistency in this choice of $k$, we examine the $3!$ ways to permute the numbers $2$, $3$, $9$ and see if any of these permutations is compatible with the list $(\ast)$. Indeed, the gaps we haven't used yet are $11$ and $12$, which is compatible with the permutation $2, 9, 3$ and also compatible with the reversed permutation $3, 9, 2$. The other four possible permutations have either $2$ in the middle or $3$ in the middle; both options are incompatible with $(\ast)$.

Answer (score 1):

A segment of length $14$ is divided into three pieces whose lengths (in order) are $x$, $y$, and $z$. The $6$ distances add up to
$$x+y+z+(x+y)+(y+z)+(x+y+z)=3x+4y+3z=3(x+y+z)+y=3\cdot14+y=42+y.$$
On the other hand, the given distances add up to
$$2+3+k+11+12+14=42+k,$$
so $y=k$, i.e., the middle piece has length $k$.

Now $2$ must be the length of a single piece (i.e. distance between consecutive points) since there is no smaller distance. Likewise $3$ must be the length of one piece, since there is only one smaller distance.

So the three pieces have lengths $2$, $k$, and $3$, and $2+k+3=14$, so $k=9$.

Check: the $6$ distances are $2$, $3$, $9$, $2+9=11$, $9+3=12$, and $2+9+3=14$.